# C++ Add secondary integer for counting values

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, arduino

I’m Alexander, I’m an Arduino UNO and C++ beginner.

I’m stuck trying to add a secondary integer for counting values. I suspect that the issue is within the first if statement in the loop.

I have two integers, one for Home and one for Away. Would anyone happen to pinpoint how I can add my secondary integer (Away) within or at least as a member of this if statement?

```
 if (currentHomeState != previousHomeState) {
previousHomeState = currentHomeState;

if (currentHomeState == On) {
  if ( (msec - msecLst) > Interval)  {
    msecLst = msec;
    numberOfGoals++; 
}
```

The complete program:

```
/*
Program for the 1960s Panco Mini-Match table top soccer game.
*/

#include <SSD1320_OLED.h>

// Initialize the display with the follow pin connections.
SSD1320 flexibleOLED(10, 9); //10 = CS, 9 = RES

// Define constants for home and away team.
const int Home = A1;
const int Away = A2;

// Define constants for LED pins.
const int LED_1 = 7;    // Pin 7 connected to a LED, turns HIGH when away team score.
const int LED_2 = 8;  // Pin 8 connected to a LED, turns HIGH when home team score.

enum { Off = HIGH, On = LOW };

#define Interval  1000

// Initalize and define states for the goal sensors.
int currentHomeState = 0, previousHomeState = 0;
int currentAwayState = 0, previousAwayState = 0;

int numberOfGoals = 0;

unsigned long msecLst = 0;

void setup() {
  //Run once

  //Initilize the display
  flexibleOLED.begin(160, 32);  //Display is 160 wide, 32 high
  flexibleOLED.clearDisplay();  //Clear display and buffer

  //Display Home score
  flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
  flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
  flexibleOLED.setCursor(45, 7);
  flexibleOLED.print(numberOfGoals);

  //Display Away score
  flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
  flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
  flexibleOLED.setCursor(95, 7);
  flexibleOLED.print(numberOfGoals);
  flexibleOLED.display();
  pinMode(Home, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED_1, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long msec = millis ();
  //Run repeatedly
  currentHomeState = digitalRead(Home);
  currentAwayState = digitalRead(Away);

  if (currentHomeState != previousHomeState) {
    previousHomeState = currentHomeState;

    if (currentHomeState == On) {
      if ( (msec - msecLst) > Interval)  {
        msecLst = msec;
        numberOfGoals++;
        Serial.println (numberOfGoals);

        flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
        flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
        flexibleOLED.setCursor(45, 6);
        flexibleOLED.print(numberOfGoals);
        flexibleOLED.display();

        digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
      }

      if (numberOfGoals == 5) {
        digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);

      }

      if (numberOfGoals == 5) {
        numberOfGoals = 0;
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);

      }

      if (numberOfGoals == 0) {

        flexibleOLED.clearDisplay(); // Clear display and buffer
        flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
        flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
        flexibleOLED.setCursor(45, 6);
        flexibleOLED.print(numberOfGoals);
        flexibleOLED.display();
        Serial.println (0);

      }

    }
  }
}
```

In another forum a user wrote to me that I needed to make a sub-function with arrays, although this is fairly new to me I came up with something like

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
string teams[2] = {"Home", "Away"};
int numbers[1];
for(int i = 0;i<1;i++) 
{
// not yet sure what to add here.
} 
for(int i = 1;i<1;i++)
{
// not yet sure what to add here.
}
return 0;
}
```

Would anyone happen to share their thoughts on whether or not I am close to figuring this one out?

Your time and help are very much appreciated.

Comment: Always, get as much programming working on the PC before running it on the Arduino.  Development is sooo much faster on a PC than on an Arduino.

Comment: Thomas, that's a great tip. Thank you.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want to do. What does `how I can add my secondary integer (Away) within or at least as a member of this if statement` mean? Are you getting an error when using your Away integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you could make your handling of teams scalable  by using introducing a team class and instantiating two objects. But since I dont think that there will be more than 2 teams a straight forward solution is to just do the same things for the away team, that you already did for the home team:

```
#include <SSD1320_OLED.h>

// Initialize the display with the follow pin connections.
SSD1320 flexibleOLED(10, 9); //10 = CS, 9 = RES

// Define constants for home and away team.
const int Home = A1;
const int Away = A2;

// Define constants for LED pins.
const int LED_Away = 7;    // Pin 7 connected to a LED, turns HIGH when away team score.
const int LED_Home = 8;  // Pin 8 connected to a LED, turns HIGH when home team score.

enum { Off = HIGH, On = LOW };

#define Interval  1000

// Initalize and define states for the goal sensors.
int currentHomeState = 0, previousHomeState = 0;
int currentAwayState = 0, previousAwayState = 0;

int homeGoals = 0;  // introduce seperate variables for home and away goals
int awayGoals = 0;

//int numberOfGoals = 0;

unsigned long msecLst = 0;

void setup() {
  //Run once

  //Initilize the display
  flexibleOLED.begin(160, 32);  //Display is 160 wide, 32 high
  flexibleOLED.clearDisplay();  //Clear display and buffer

  //Display Home score
  flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
  flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
  flexibleOLED.setCursor(45, 7);
  flexibleOLED.print(homeGoals);

  //Display Away score
  flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
  flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
  flexibleOLED.setCursor(95, 7);
  flexibleOLED.print(awayGoals);
  flexibleOLED.display();
  pinMode(Home, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(Away, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED_home, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_away, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long msec = millis ();
  //Run repeatedly
  currentHomeState = digitalRead(Home);
  currentAwayState = digitalRead(Away);
//-------------handle home --------------------------------
  if (currentHomeState != previousHomeState) {
    previousHomeState = currentHomeState;

    if (currentHomeState == On) {
      if ( (msec - msecLst) > Interval)  {
        msecLst = msec;
        homeGoals++;
        Serial.println (homeGoals);

        flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
        flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
        flexibleOLED.setCursor(45, 6);
        flexibleOLED.print(homeGoals);
        flexibleOLED.display();

        digitalWrite(LED_1, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_1, LOW);
      }

      if (homeGoals == 5) {
        digitalWrite(LED_home, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, HIGH);

      }

      if (homeGoals == 5) {
        homeGoals = 0;
        awayGoals = 0;
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_home, LOW);

      }

      if (homeGoals == 0) {

        flexibleOLED.clearDisplay(); // Clear display and buffer
        flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
        flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
        flexibleOLED.setCursor(45, 6);
        flexibleOLED.print(homeGoals);
        flexibleOLED.display();
        Serial.println (0);

      }
//----------------handle away
  if (currentAwayState != previousAwayState) {
    previousAwayState = currentAwayState;

    if (currentAwayState == On) {
      if ( (msec - msecLst) > Interval)  {
        msecLst = msec;
        awayGoals++;
        Serial.println (awayGoals);

        flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
        flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
        flexibleOLED.setCursor(45, 6);
        flexibleOLED.print(awayGoals);
        flexibleOLED.display();

        digitalWrite(LED_away, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, LOW);
      }

      if (awayGoals == 5) {
        digitalWrite(LED_away, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, LOW);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, HIGH);

      }

      if (awayGoals == 5) {
        homeGoals = 0;
        awayGoals = 0;
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(LED_away, LOW);

      }

      if (awayGoals == 0) {

        flexibleOLED.clearDisplay(); // Clear display and buffer
        flexibleOLED.setContrast(255);
        flexibleOLED.setFontType(2); //7-segment display style characters, 10x16-pixels each.
        flexibleOLED.setCursor(45, 6);
        flexibleOLED.print(awayGoals);
        flexibleOLED.display();
        Serial.println (0);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I did not check the code for errors. Also in general you should consider to write seperate functions to make the code easier to read.

Comment: This is in deed very interesting and the code you wrote definitively has my attention. Initially this was my idea as well, but I haven't yet got enough understanding to think around with classes in the way that you present here. Thank you for the time and knowledge shared.

Comment: You mentioned that I in general should use functions , I assume for these types of programs. Would that be something that could handle the teams in your opinion?

Comment: for sure you could organize your code in a better way if you use functions. for example, if you put all the instructions, that are necessary to control the OLED and to print some message into a function, your code gets more readable. the goal of that is to create layers in your program that seperate what you want to do from how you have to do it.